# ADB on CYGWIN (path maybe?)

Tags: android, path, cygwin, recovery, file-recovery

Taken from here:
http://www.asoftech.com/articles/android-enable-mass-storage.html

When I try this command:

```
adb forward tcp:5555 tcp:5555
```

it says

```
-bash: adb: command not found"
```

I already entered in the PATH values.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: compare the location of adb.exe with the value of PATH. The output of `echo $PATH` will give some hints. Check also file permissions with `ls -l adb.exe`

Comment: Using a Windows OS

Answer (score 3):

You can try `adb` command line first. I think you probably didn't add adb path successfully.

### Add `adb` path:

1. find adb path. For example, my path is `Z:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools`
2. do following commands.

   `export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/Z/AndroidSDK/platform-tools`

You should add path now